# call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'WC_Rapyd' does not have a method 'install'

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, ajax, hooks, child-theme

We've installed the Woocommerce Rapyd Payments plugin and have the issue that the payment option is not loading on the front end. Query Monitor is showing the above warning message, but I haven't been able to fix the issue. I deactivated all plugins and there were no conflict issues. Switch themes and Rapyd then works ok.

Issue seems that the plugin scripts are not loading properly when our child theme is active.
Query Monitor states these locations for the issue;

wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:287
do_action('admin_init')
wp-admin/admin.php:175

I tried adding the admin_init function calling the class from the plugin file as a snippet in the child functions.php file, but still getting the same issue. Any help on this would be appreciated.

.... will now forward to the plugin developer.

Comment: seems like an issue with the plugin. you should get in contact with the developer, since this question is not a wordpress problem, but a 3rd party plugin..

Comment: I'd guess the problem will look something like `add_action( 'admin_init', array( 'WC_Rapyd', 'install' ) );`, or `add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'install' ) );` inside the WC_Rapyd class definition itself - it's not a case of setting up your own extra admin_init handler I don't think. Why your child theme makes a difference I've no idea, unless you're explicitly calling WC_Rapyd from your child theme? I can't think why you'd need to.

Comment: Yes, the plugin code is: private function __construct() { add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'install' ) ); $this->init(); }. Perhaps script isn't enqueued in correct order, but I now have ticket open with plugin developer.